# Please anyone helps me how to run java code in resteasy automatically when deploy in jboss?

Tags: resteasy

I'm new here and new in resteasy. I have resteasy web application running on Jboss. I want to run specific code in my application once when JBoss starts or when this application is deployed. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ServletContextListener`.

Here is a simple tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/